# Laravel - There is any way to get all running middlewares?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I wonder if there is any way in Laravel to get all running middlewares in a route.

For example:
- I want to know in route "/example", if I can easily check which are all involved Middlewares that are called.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`artisan route:list --path=example` will list the route details including middleware and the controller.